# Efficient way for generating N arrays of random numbers between different ranges

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to generate N arrays of fixed length n of random numbers with numpy, but arrays must have numbers varying between different ranges.

So for example, I want to generate N=100 arrays of size n=5 and each array must have its numbers between:

- First number between 0 and 10
- Second number between 20 and 100

and so on...

First idea that comes to my mind is doing something like:

```
first=np.random.randint(0,11, 100) 
second=np.random.randint(20,101, 100)
...
```

And then I should nest them, Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: How do you define the ranges? As for 100 different ranges, there must be some programmatic way to define it?

Comment: Are you generating these arrays repeatedly in the script, or just once at the start.  If just once, it's probably not worth worrying about efficiency, and just go ahead and iterate on the 100 ranges.

Comment: @hpaulj These arrays are generated once in the script

Comment: @Psidom All arrays have the same size and same ranges for each of its elements. There will not be N ranges, only n ranges.

Comment: How about generating a (100,5) `randint`, and scaling each row differently?

Comment: Show us how you would generate one such array.  I don't think we understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put them inside another array and iterate them through their index

```
from np.random import randint
array_holder = [[] for i in range(N)] # Get N arrays in a holder
ab_holder = [[a1, b1], [a2, b2]]
for i in range(len(array_holder)): # You iterate over each array
    [a, b] = [ab_holder[i][0], ab_holder[i][1]]
    for j in range(size): # Size is the ammount of elements you want in each array
        array_holder[i].append(randint(a, b)) # Where a is your base and b ends the range
```

Comment: That's why they're variables, insert in that code whatever makes a and b change, edited code and added a way to hardcode a and b values (In case they're not returned from a function)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility. Setting `ranges` indicates both what the ranges of the individual parts of each arrays must be and how many there are. `size` is the number of values to sample in each individual part of an array. `N` is the size of the Monte-Carlo sample. `arrays` is the result.

```
import numpy as np

ranges = [ (0, 10), (20, 100) ]
size = 5
N = 100

arrays = [ ]
for n in range(N):
    one_array = []
    for r in ranges:
        chunk = np.random.randint(*r, size=size)
        one_array.append(chunk)
    arrays.append(one_array)
```

It might make an appreciable difference to use numpy's `append` in place of Python's but I've written this in this way to make it easier to read (and to write :)).